# @SQLResultSetMapping Column not found issue

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a query like so

```
                    FROM RUN cr
                    LEFT JOIN OFFER_SET os ON cr.ID = os.RUN_ID
                    LEFT JOIN AA aa ON cr.ID = aa.RUN_ID
                    LEFT JOIN POLICY ex ON cr.ID = ex.RUN_ID
                    WHERE cr.ID = '1d4101ea2'
```

and created a mapping entity so I could get a result set back in the proper format. That looks like this.

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="OutcomeDetails",
        entities={
                @EntityResult(entityClass=OutcomeDetailsEntity.class, fields={
                        @FieldResult(name="reason", column="REASON_CD"),
                        @FieldResult(name="status", column="STATUS_CD"),
                        @FieldResult(name="countered", column="COUNTERED_FLG"),
                        @FieldResult(name="id", column="ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="version", column="VERSION"),
                        @FieldResult(name="createdD", column="CREATED_D"),
                        @FieldResult(name="modifiedD", column="MODIFIED_D"),
                        @FieldResult(name="corrId", column="CORRELATION_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="policyId", column="POLICY_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="modelId", column="MODEL_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="srcId", column="SRC_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="refId", column="REF_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="serviceName", column="SERVICE_NAME"),
                        @FieldResult(name="policy", column="POLICY"),
                        @FieldResult(name="policyVersion", column="POLICY_VERSION"),
                })
        })
```

When I run this query in a sql console it works fine. When I run it through the code I get this error

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'corrId' not found.`

The code looks like this

```
        try {
            Query q = cdsEntityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT aa.REASON_CD, os.COUNTERED_FLG, ex.STATUS_CD, cr.* " +
                    "FROM RUN cr " +
                    "LEFT JOIN OFFER_SET os ON cr.ID = os.RUN_ID " +
                    "LEFT JOIN AA aa ON cr.ID = aa.RUN_ID " +
                    "LEFT JOIN POLICY ex ON cr.ID = ex.RUN_ID " +
                    "WHERE cr.ID=:id ", OutcomeDetailsEntity.class);
            q.setParameter("id",id);
            result = q.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
```

I have looked around, and although people have had similar problems none of the solutions there have worked. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Maybe assign a column alias in your query and map against that? https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/FieldResult Not a definite solution, just an idea.

Comment: @DavidS when I comment out all the lines but one, I still get this issue -- edit: this seems to work on subset of data, I will try it with all the data and report back

Comment: @sf8193 Could you please show your class `OutcomeDetailsEntity`. And could you please try to replace `cr.*` by comma separated columns.

Comment: @DavidS your answer works, if you would like to put it as a proper answer and I can mark it as correct

Comment: Thanks for the offer, sf8193, I appreciate it, but don't worry about it: I should really get back to my own debugging. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone coming across this later, I needed to change the `name` attribute and `column` attribute to the same thing, so it looked like this

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="OutcomeDetails",
        entities={
                @EntityResult(entityClass=OutcomeDetailsEntity.class, fields={
                        @FieldResult(name="REASON_CD", column="REASON_CD"),
                        @FieldResult(name="STATUS_CD", column="STATUS_CD"),
                        @FieldResult(name="COUNTERED_FLG", column="COUNTERED_FLG"),
                        @FieldResult(name="ID", column="ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="VERSION", column="VERSION"),
                        @FieldResult(name="CREATED_D", column="CREATED_D"),
                        @FieldResult(name="MODIFIED_D", column="MODIFIED_D"),
                        @FieldResult(name="CORRELATION_ID", column="CORRELATION_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="POLICY_ID", column="POLICY_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="MODEL_ID", column="MODEL_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="SRC_ID", column="SRC_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="REF_ID", column="REF_ID"),
                        @FieldResult(name="SERVICE_NAME", column="SERVICE_NAME"),
                        @FieldResult(name="POLICY", column="POLICY"),
                        @FieldResult(name="POLICY_VERSION", column="POLICY_VERSION"),
                })
        })
```

Comment: I've just run into this and I changed my column and name to match like your's but I still get this error?